# find the UMVUE of a parametric function

Tags: statistical-inference, nonparametric-statistics

Assume $(X_1, . . . , X_n)$ is an i.i.d. sample from $P = \{f : f$ is a pdf and $E_f|X|< ∞\}$. Use the conditioning approach to find an UMVUE of $τ (f) =
(E_f (X))^2$.

Can someone provide a hint for this? No idea where to start.